# Is this "Security Info Required" prompt legitimate?

Tags: iphone

I attempted to install an application this afternoon, and was presented with the below security screen stating:

> **Security Info Required**
>
> To help ensure the security  of your Apple ID,
> you must confirm your password and answer your security questions.

I have never seen this prompt before, and wanted to confirm that it was legitimate and from Apple, and not something triggered by the new app (though it doesn't appear to have installed). I cancelled out of the prompt for now.

[image: Security Info Required]

Comment: possible duplicate of [App Store asking for credentials?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48438/app-store-asking-for-credentials)

Comment: The wording on these two is distinct enough that having both around isn't of harm to the site. Thanks for linking, as now someone that sees one is likely to see the other if one doesn't answer it to their satisfaction.

Comment: Just had to say, I love your background wallpaper.

Comment: @JasonSalaz I wish I remember the source of where I got it from. Unfortunately, I don't, but here's a link to the copy I have if you'd like it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbcrkwmu5jngaj8/zelda-wp.JPG

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is. Here's [Ars Technica reporting](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2012/04/apple-prompting-users-for-security-questions-to-bolster-apple-id-security.ars) on the matter:

> "Apple has begun to ask iOS device owners for the answers to security
>   questions as part of an effort to beef up Apple ID security. iPhone
>   users began widely reporting the change on Thursday, though the
>   changes actually began happening sometime in the last 24 hours. Not
>   all iOS users have seen the request pop up yet, however, leaving some
>   confused about whether the prompt is legitimately from Apple.
>
> The prompt that shows up on an iOS device says "Security Info
>   Required." It proceeds to ask the user to select from a handful of
>   security questions and provide answers."

The screenshot in the article is identical to yours:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before, when I have switched which Apple ID I am using, or if I am trying to upgrade an app that was previously purchased on another ID etc.

If it is definitely only appearing when you purchase an app directly from the App store App, then I say it is safe.  It's possible your card has expired.