# Installing (any) App asks for my password again and security question's answers

Tags: applications, install, iphone, malware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this “Security Info Required” prompt legitimate?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48920/is-this-security-info-required-prompt-legitimate)

I am trying to install Wunderlist (pick any other App), the App Store asks for my password which is fine. But once I key in my password, I get this prompt.

Security Info Required

To help ensure the security of your Apple ID, you must choose and answer security questions. (Cancel / Continue).

If I click on Continue, I am asked to enter my Apple ID password?

Is there a virus or a malware on my iPhone 4S?

Comment: [Ars technica reports it's legit](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2012/04/apple-prompting-users-for-security-questions-to-bolster-apple-id-security.ars). Still – I'd wish to read a more elaborate answer than this comment and perhaps see some official cites on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

This was a [recent change](http://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/971901) to increase security for the many iTunes/App Store accounts. This is not malware or anything you have to be concerned with, just Apple increasing security.